# Android Kotlin: Translate animation on view is not working

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am working on an Android Kotlin project. I am applying animation on views. Starting from the basics, I am trying to animate an image view from the bottom of the screen to the center of the screen.

I have an XML layout with the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_image_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/memento_text_logo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/main_logo_image_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/main_tv_slogan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/main_slogan"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am animating the logo image translating from the bottom to the center (where it is originally) in the activity with the following code.

```
private fun animateMainLogo() {
        val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, main_image_logo.y)

        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener {
            val value = it.animatedValue as Float
            main_image_logo.translationY = value
        }

        valueAnimator.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        valueAnimator.duration = 1000
        valueAnimator.start()
    }
```

When I run the code, it is not animating the view. It is just there where it is and static. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`translationY` of view in layout is 0. If you want to animate it from bottom to current position - you should change `translationY` values from some positive value to 0.

```
private fun animateLogo() {
    val translationYFrom = 400f
    val translationYTo = 0f
    val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(translationYFrom, translationYTo).apply {
        interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        duration = 1000
    }
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener {
        val value = it.animatedValue as Float
        main_image_logo?.translationY = value
    }
    valueAnimator.start()
}
```

Same thing can be done this way:

```
private fun animateLogo() {
        main_image_logo.translationY = 400f
        main_image_logo.animate()
            .translationY(0f)
            .setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator())
            .setStartDelay(1000)
            .start()
    }
```

Add this lines to `LinearLayout` and `ConstraintLayout` because without them `LinearLayout` will cut of parts of animated view when it is outside of `LinearLayout` bounds.

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Or make `main_image_logo` direct child of root `ConstraintLayout`. Here is result:
[image: result]